# Unable to use mysqlnd methods

Tags: php, cpanel, mysqlnd

I am creating a WebService using Slim framework in php. it works well for `POST REQUEST` but when I use `GET REQUEST` I come across error stating

> Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

I've created another file for testing purpose. which contains the code below. As in the first check I find that extension is loaded but my second check goes false as I check any native method of mysqlnd

```
if (extension_loaded('mysqlnd')) {
echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}
  $mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');
 if($mysqlnd) {

   echo 'function exists';
}
```

My PHP version is PHP Version 5.5.31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have administrator privileges on your cPanel machine.

  - If you're running EasyApache 3: You need to re-run EasyApache and enable the mysqlnd and mysqli extensions, making sure to disable "Mysql of the system" option.  You can find that in the Extended Options screen.
  - If you're running EasyApache 4: You need to install the ea-php55-php-mysqlnd package.  You can do that using WHM >> EasyApache 4, or via command-line (yum install ea-php55-php-mysqlnd).
- If you do not have administrator privileges, you need to ask your administrator to add both mysqlnd and mysqli.

  - If your administrator says that mysqlnd and/or mysqli is already installed, then you want to add "extension=mysqlnd.so" and "extension=mysqlnd_mysqli.so" to your php.ini file.